# Найти буквы большого регистра и вставить перед ней разделитель

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Можно ли с помощью регулярок в notepad++ найти в тексте места где буквы малого и большого регистра стоят рядом, вот так: "Абвг АбвгАбвг" и вставить между ними разделитель: "|"  чтобы получилось вот так: "Абвг Абвг|Абвг" ?

Answer (score 0):

Легко! notepad++ поддерживает regexp поэтому отформатировать можно все и вся :
в твоем случае это `([a-zа-я])([A-ZА-Я])` => `$1|$2`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]